# ¿Como agregar y eliminar selects con jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

Hola tengo un código en jquery que me funciona perfecto para agregar nuevos inputs el problema es que necesito también para mi sistema agregar selects de forma dinámica y la verdad no le entiendo a la sintaxis de jquery. Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Por cierto el select hace una consulta a la base de datos.

```
 // Añadir caja de texto.
    $(container).append('<input type=text required="required" name ="fields[]" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
    'placeholder="Producto ' + iCnt + '" />');
     <select name="producto">
     <?php

                        $sql = "Select producto from productos";

        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
           while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
           }
         ?>
     </select>
```

Comment: Osea, quieres agregar un control `select` con todo y `option` desde jquery, no con PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es agregar controles `select` con jquery, puedes creando el elemento `select` en memoria, luego crear cada `option` al `select` y luego agregar el `select` al elemento donde quieres que aparezca.

Aqui un ejemplo:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 
  var select = $(document.createElement("select"));
  
  // agregamos las opciones al select
  var options = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo"];
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
  {
    var option = $(document.createElement("option"));
    option.val(options[i]);
    option.text(options[i]);
    
    //agregamos el option al select
    select.append(option);
  }
  
  // agregamos el select al documento
  $("body").append(select);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Crear select</button>
```